# MySQL - Monitoring Disk I/O Per Table

Tags: mysql

What I want to diagnose is how much disk read/write is being done over time per table(each table has a single file).

I have monitoring for the total disk read/write and monitoring for slow query log, general queries log.

Comment: You should only activate the general-log for debugging an issue - it can place a very heavy load on the server!

Comment: @Vérace yea I know, I use the slow_query_log + `monyog` tools for query diagnostic

Comment: To obtain real DISK read/write activity You must monitoring this activity on OS (filesystem requestor driver) level. If You'll do so, remember those monitoring is extremely expencive.

Comment: Slow log indicates that query is slow; staring at query shows that query needs to touch a lot of blocks.  Would you like to show us a 'slow' query for us to analyze like this?